# xpath internal link parsing

Tags: xpath, vbscript, xml-parsing, qtp

I have got a soap response from a webservice where it looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Body>
  <multiref id="1">
    <cpuclock>2300</cpuclock>
    <memoryComponent>
      <item href="#2"/>
      <item href="#3"/>
    </memoryComponent>
  </multiref>
  <multiref id="2" type="ns2:MemoryComponent">
    <type>RAM</type>
    <quantity>2048</quantity>
  </multiref>
  <multiref id="3" type="ns3:MemoryComponent">
    <type>RAM</type>
    <quantity>1024</quantity>
  </multiref>
</Body>
```

What I am trying to achieve is to recover the memoryComponent elements.
Since I am using the XMLUtil of VBScript/QTP, I've been trying to workaround using XPATH (by predicates). Ends-with is not supported by my QTP framework version.
Any suggestions?

TIA!

Comment: If you want us to help with your code you need to show your code first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found a way to retrieve the elements I wanted.

```
Set childElements = XMLFile.ChildElementsByPath("/Body/multiref[contains(@type,'MemoryComponent')]")
```

This workaround suits my needs pretty well.
Thanks!